# How to suppress LLVM auto synthesis warning?

Tags: objective-c, llvm-clang

I'm getting the following llvm warning

Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'imageView' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property.

When I Googled the error message if found a link to a LLVM Bug 16693.  But I couldn't find a way to suppress the warning.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: check there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384364/auto-property-synthesis-property-and-inheritance

Comment: Is it possible that you're overriding a property of a super class in which the super declares readonly? (i.e. UITableViewCell) Cause that's what that warning sounds like. As a test try naming the property something else. (i.e. notMySupersImageView)

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Lavender is right. You can try it out for yourself. Go to the public interface of a UIViewController subclass and add the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIViewController* parentViewController;
```

You'll get the same warning. And if you check the `UIViewController` docs, sure enough, that property is already declared as `readonly`.