# Auto property synthesis (@property) and inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, warnings, xcode5.1

With XCode 5.1, a new warning appears. It made me understand *-obviously-* that I was doing something wrong.

The idea was to have an object (a model) and it's mutable version which inherits from the original class. So the idea is to open a property which was `readonly` to `readwrite`

```
@interface Car : NSObject
    @property (strong, readonly) NSString *name;
@end

@interface MutableCar : Car
    @property (strong, readwrite) NSString *name;
@end
```

Those needs to be in separate files (like two normal classes).

And it gives this warning :

```
Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'name' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property
```

So I would like to know what is the right solution to do something like it, if it's even possible. if it's needed to write accessors and avoid using auto synthesis, etc. Just please be precise and support your answer with documentation or whatever.

Comment: I can't reproduce the warnings with the given code.

Comment: I did and yes, you need to put it in separate file to have it (create both classes)

Comment: Any flag I could pass or ignore to get rid of this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'd suggest to explicitly synthesize the property on your MutableCar implementation. As in:

```
@implementation MutableCar

@synthesize name;

@end
```

That way clang won't try to use [autosynthesis](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-autosynthesis-of-properties)

Edit:

If you don't want to use encapsulation and for other reason you need to access the ivar from the parent class, then you need to do a little bit more effort:

First the Car .h file remains the same (I added a printVar method to print the ivar and property):

```
@interface Car : NSObject

- (void)printVar;

@property (strong, readonly) NSString *name;

@end
```

Now on the .m file, I'm implementing the printVar method and also adding a class extension to tell clang to create the setter:

```
// Private class extension, causes setName: to be created but not exposed.
@interface Car ()

@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Car

- (void)printVar
{
    NSLog(@"<Car> Hello %@, ivar: %@", self.name, _name);
}

@end
```

Now you can create your MutableCar.h as before:

```
@interface MutableCar : Car

@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end
```

and your MutableCar.m should looks like this:

```
@implementation MutableCar

@dynamic name;

- (void)printVar
{
    [super printVar];
    NSLog(@"<MutableCar> Hello %@", self.name);
}

@end
```

That way the _name ivar on the parent is actually written using the parent setter and you can access it.

Comment: Does it imply any difference of functionality or will it be the same ?

Comment: After use it, it is not a good answer, it's accurate and remove the warning, but it changes the way it works since it creates a new iVar in the child class rather than use the parent's one like it's protected.

Comment: @anc Can you show me your exact case?. Do you have a specific ivar for that property?. This case should work, see this example: https://gist.github.com/Reflejo/11c91b929bf021308b95

Comment: @ancAinu You'll get: "Car1: Testing name" and "Car2: Testing name". Do you need to explicitly access the ivar on MutableCar?