# What does this objective-c property synthesis warning mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Since upgrading to Xcode 5.1, I'm starting to see the following warning in some code my project uses. I'm trying to figure out what it means.

Warning: `Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'responseHeader' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property`

The code where it's occurring, in the .m file:

```
@interface S3Response ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
@end
```

The previous declaration of the property, in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
```

There is no `@synthesize` statement for that property, nor are `responseHeader` or `setResponseHeader` defined as methods. There is however an explicit definition of an ivar named `responseHeader`.

Seems pretty straightforward to me: property is declared as read-only for users of the class, but read-write locally so the class can set it.

What does this warning mean, and what should I do about it?

Comment: Try changing the header definition to `(nonatomic, readonly, retain)`.

Comment: That doesn't fix the warning. Nor does it help me understand what the warning means. :)

Comment: What class are you subclassing? Does *that* have a `responseHeader` property?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, no. Amended the question to clarify.

Comment: @Kevin, it's subclassing `NSObject`. I did however find an explicit declaration of an ivar named `responseHeader` though; amended the question.

Comment: Look at [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6H8.png). Click on "Property declared here." Where does that highlight?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That code seems to be from the [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/),
and `S3Response` is a subclass of `AmazonServiceResponse`.

The public `AmazonServiceResponse` interface defines a read-only property

```
@interface AmazonServiceResponse:NSObject
// ...
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
@end
```

which is redefined as read-write in a class extension in the implementation file:

```
@interface AmazonServiceResponse ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
@end
```

Now the *subclass* `S3Response` also wants read-write access to this property,
and therefore also defines in the class extension of its implementation file:

```
@interface S3Response ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
@end
```

The compiler complains because – when compiling "S3Response.m" – it does not know
that a *setter* for the property exists in the superclass (it does not read 
the *implementation file* of the superclass at that point). Also the compiler cannot
simply synthesize a setter in the subclass, because it cannot not know that the
property is backed-up by an instance variable in the superclass.

But *you know* that a setter will be generated, so you can remove the warning by
adding a `@dynamic` declaration to the subclass implementation:

```
@implementation S3Response
@dynamic responseHeader;
...
```

`@dynamic` is a "promise" to the compiler that all necessary accessor methods will
be available at runtime.

Comment: Sure enough, this fixed the issue. Plus points for figuring out exactly what code I was talking about :)  Still, that's a pretty crummy warning message.

Comment: in Xcode6, it does NOT work, you need to follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384364/auto-property-synthesis-property-and-inheritance

Comment: @Jacky: Can you clarify your statement? I just verified with Xcode 6 beta 4 and the  AWS SDK for iOS v1.7.1 that my suggested solution still fixes the compiler warning. Adding `@dynamic ...` is also suggested in the answer to the question that you linked to. - Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is as follows.

By default, if don't write ownership (weak/retain/strong/assign) explicitly, xCode will check the type automatically. So in case of NSDictionary it will be *strong*. Thus, in interface you will have

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
```

Then it will be contradict you private implementation definition

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *responseHeader;
```

Compilator doesn't match strong and retain under property synthesizing though it is formally the same thing.

To cure situation you can write *retain* in both cases, or more correct, you should not write retain at all. It will be strong by default in both definitions.

Comment: `strong` and `retain` are equivalent, so if this is true, it should be considered a bug. (Although a pedantic warning from the compiler about the mismatch would probably be appropriate.)

Comment: It is true from the ownership viewpoint. But it seems that some automatic mechanisms of ARC distinguish them for some reason.

Comment: "strong" and "retain" are complete synonyms and can be mixed without causing any warning.